# Passing variable between HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have two HTML file: a.html and b.html. I have a link in a that open b

How can I make a JavaScript function in file a so that when I click the link, it send a string to b, open b and then a variable in b will store the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing this client side, then you have to pass the data from the first page in the query string of the URI for the second page. Then you can parse it out of the [`location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) in the second page.

Comment: Simply link to b.html like this: b.html?variable=value and retrieve it with JavaScript: window.location.